# Changing/Resize image size from stream only for read or view in picturebox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, stream, devexpress, picturebox

I want to change the size of the image or Resize image from stream only for read in each picturebox to small or not display the original size of the image and then when I double click the image appears with the original size. I'm using "FocusedRowChanged" in DevExpress.XtraGrid because the image data there are thousands hence it makes it a bit slow when moving from row to row gridview.
Is there a best solution or recommendation?

Thanks

```
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath1) Then
            PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1)), True, False)
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath2) Then
                PictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2)), True, False)
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath3) Then
                    PictureEdit3.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath3)), True, False)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath4) Then
                        PictureEdit4.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath4)), True, False)
                        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath5) Then
                            PictureEdit5.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath5)), True, False)
                            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath6) Then
                                PictureEdit6.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath6)), True, False)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Private Sub PictureEditAll_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureEdit1.DoubleClick, PictureEdit2.DoubleClick, PictureEdit3.DoubleClick, PictureEdit4.DoubleClick, PictureEdit5.DoubleClick, PictureEdit6.DoubleClick
        Dim picEdit As PictureEdit = DirectCast(sender, PictureEdit)
        Dim f2 As New Preview(picEdit.Image)
        f2.Show(Me)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Just assign the file path to the `ImageLocation` property of the `PictureBox`.

Comment: Why not just set the `Size` of each `PictureBox` to an appropriate value and then set the `SizeMode` to something like `Zoom`? That will display the image at the size you want without actually changing the size of the `Image` object.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , I've tried the one you suggested keep making slow at the time of gridview row switching